# Can client-side javascript create a file download that is too big to fit in memory?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, indexeddb, fileapi, mediastream

I am using [captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) to record from a HTML canvas, and currently use the example code in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API. However, this only works for short recordings as each blob is stored in memory.

I’d like to be able to record for long periods of time e.g. >1 hour and let the user download the resulting .webm/.mkv file. If this sounds unusual, it’s because I’m using the web browser for an (open source) scientific application and need to know what was displayed during an experiment :).

It’s simple enough to adapt the MDN code to store each blob in IndexedDB instead of an in-memory array, but I’m stuck on how to construct the download without creating an enormous blob that would exhaust memory:

```
var blob = new Blob([IDBchunk1, IDBchunk2, ...], {
  type: "video/webm"
});
```

Another approach would be to construct a “streaming” download, but not sure if this is possible.

One workable, but horribly inefficient solution is to use WebRTC to send the stream back to nodejs server, append each blob to on-disk video file on server, then serve the video download over http. I dislike this solution as involves the complexity of setting up webRTC + requires massive bandwidth back and forth.

Let me know if you have any thoughts for how to do this on client-side only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, at least, the `new Blob([IDBchunk1, IDBchunk2, ...]...)` approach does not require *any* of the blobs to be loaded into memory. The new blob internally references the dependent blobs/files, and a read over the blob (e.g. during download) pulls bytes from the dependent blobs as needed.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right and IndexedDB is unnecessary. It appears that Chrome, at least, will auto-transfer blobs from memory to a file as needed: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/storage/browser/blob/README.md